# Display page title for an article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have an article which is included in a page with anchor tag. It is not associated with any menu. My problem is when I visit that page , it is not showing article title as page title. Please help me. Im using joomla 2.5

Thanks in advance
iijb

Comment: What you could do is, create a hidden menu, then a new menu item but don't display it in any modules position. Link your article to the menu item, retreive the link and use this.

Comment: "retreive the link and use this."      can you describe it.

Comment: on the left hand side, in the "Details" are of where you are creating your menu item, there is a "Link" box where you will be able to copy the link. sorry for bad explanation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you.

Create a menu items as `innermenu`. Admin->Menus->Menu Manager->Add New Menu.

In the following Menu Item, you have to create one menu with the and include the article to the following menu.

Then copy the url of the article and save the menu process.After that an itemid is generated for the menu.Include the itemid with the and run the url, then the page title will be displayed.